# How can I disabl multiline property in UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, infragistics

Is there a property (displayed in  VS) that I can change so that I do not have the option to select multiple rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the grid's custom designer dialog: Feature Picker -> Selection -> Row Selection and make a choice.  Perhaps "Don't allow" or "Single select" will do what you need.

Or, in VS properties dialog: Layout -> DisplayLayout -> Override -> SelectTypeRow offers similar choices.

Answer (score 0):

In the designer and for Header:

Control Settings > Display Layout > Override > WrapHeaderText = false